# ratio distribution of two dependent Poisson variables

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Consider a homogeneous Poisson point process $\Phi$ in a disc with radius 
$R$, and the density of $\Phi$  is $\lambda$ per unit area. 
Denote the total number of points in the whole disc as N, and that of points in a sub-disc with radius $D < R$ inside of the whole disc as Ns.

According to the property of PPP, we know that
$$ N \sim Poisson(\lambda \pi R^2)$$ and $$Ns \sim Poisson(\lambda \pi D^2).$$

It is abviously $N$ and $N_s$ are dependent.
My question is how can I find the ratio distribution of $$Z= \frac{Ns}{N}.$$
Many thanks for your answers.